# How to extract content from a single file by using two specified points with dd?

Tags: files, dd, split

Taking from [here](https://0day.work/sunshine-ctf-2016-writeups/), there is a steganography part in an image file called moon.png. It led me thinking, how would I extract a say Zlib that is between 944 and 411781 using something like dd.

```
$> binwalk moon.png 

DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0             0x0             PNG image, 600 x 593, 8-bit/color RGB, non-interlaced
290           0x122           Unix path: /www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"> <rdf:Description rdf:about="" xmlns:xmpMM="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/mm/" xmlns:stRef=
944           0x3B0           Zlib compressed data, best compression
411781        0x64885         Zip archive data, encrypted at least v1.0 to extract, compressed size: 35, uncompressed size: 23, name: flag.txt
411976        0x64948         End of Zip archive
```

The author did `dd if=./moon.png of=./moon.zip skip=411781 bs=1`, but that works for only starting point 0 to 411781.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The author actually extracted the ZIP part from the file. That begins at 411781. By default the rest of the file from there is copied.

`skip` moves over the specified number of blocks (since `bs=1`, 1 block is 1 byte) from the beginning before copying. So to get the 'zlib' part you would want:

```
dd if=./moon.png of=./moon.zlib skip=944 count=410837 bs=1
```

`count` is the number of blocks to copy from that point. So here the count is the end position minus the number of skipped blocks/bytes: 411781-944=410837.